# XSL group elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been trying to create an XSL transform that will group and sum XML elements, but without success.

My input XML:

```
    <Data>
        <ElementOne>10</ElementOne>
        <ElementTwo>20</ElementTwo>
        <ElementFour>30</ElementThree>
        ... a lot more elements ...    
    </Data>

    <Data>
        <ElementOne>100</ElementOne>
        <ElementTwo>200</ElementTwo>
        <ElementFour>300</ElementThree>
        ...  
    </Data>

    ... more data elements
```

The XML that I want to create:

```
<Summary>
    <ElementOne>110</ElementOne> <!-- sum of all ElementOne values in the input-->
    <ElementTwo>220</ElementTwo>
    <ElementFour>330</ElementThree>
    ....
</Summary>
```

I know that I can get a sum using something like this:

```
<ElementOne><xsl:value-of select="sum(Data/ElementOne)</ElementOne>
```

The problem with this is that I have to specify each element by name which is something I'm trying to avoid. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: I'm using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 2.0 you can use

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*[Data]">
    <Summary>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Data/*" group-by="node-name(.)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group())"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Summary>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/ejivdGX. (Note: the use `<xsl:template match="*[Data]">` is done mainly as you did not show the name of the parent element of the `Data` elements).